# Rvest: getting node text and not its childen's text

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

The method `html_text()` (from R Package rvest) concatenates the text of the node and **all its children**.  I would like to extract **only the father's text**.

Forthe following example, `html_text()` gives **HELLO GOODBYE**.

I want to get just **GOODBYE**. How can I get it?

```html
<div class="joke">
  <div class="div_inside">
    <div class="title_inside">
      <a class="link" href="sompage.htm">HELLO</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  GOODBYE
</div>
```

Comment: question + minimal code + minimal data is the usual idiom for an SO question

Comment: `read_html('your_html_script') %>% html_nodes(xpath = '//div[@class="joke"]/node()[not(self::div)]') %>% html_text()`?

Comment: That works perfectly, @Abdou. I expecteced something from the rvest package, but the flexibilty of xpath is enough. Thank you very much!

Comment: You're most welcome! Maybe there is another solution out there. I will add this one as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to grab the main `div` tag with `class` "joke" without picking up its children, using xpath:

```
library(rvest)

read_html('your_html_script') %>%
    html_nodes(xpath = '//div[@class="joke"]/node()[not(self::div)]') %>% 
    html_text()
```

Thanks!