# Xpath removing children

Tags: r, xpath

I am trying to webscrape a forum using R, RVest. However I'm having a little trouble trying to remove children from my xml_nodeset.
So the html I'm trying to webscrape is as followed:

```
<div id="post_message_1234">
 <div style="margin:20px; margin-top:5px; ">
  <div class="smallfont" style="margin-bottom:2px">Quote:</div>
  <table cellpadding="6" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td class="alt2" style="border:1px inset">
            <div>
                Originally Posted by <strong>John Doe</strong>
            </div>
                This is the post inside the quote
        </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
 </div>
  This is the post outside the quote
</div>
```

What I need from this piece of html is 'This is the post outside the quote', which is the original post. And the piece I dont want is the quoted post inside the class "alt2", 'This is the post inside the quote'.
 
Further more there are multiple post_messages on each page. And there can be multiple quotes in each post_message. 
The code I'm using right now is able to get all the text inside each post. But is also containing the text which is inside the quote (something I do not want).

```
link %>%
   read_html() %>%
   html_nodes(xpath = '//*[contains(@id, "post_message_")]') %>%
   html_text()
```

How can I get only the text outside the quote ('This is the post outside the quote'), preferably using xpath?

Answer (score 1):

How about removing the child DIV?

```
link %>%
   read_html() %>%
   html_nodes(xpath = '//*[contains(@id, "post_message_")]/node()[not(self::div)]') %>%
   html_text()
```

Check out this working example for imbd that I tested using [this](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rvest/versions/0.3.2/topics/html_text) compiler

```
read_html('http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1490017/') %>%
    html_nodes(xpath = '//div[@class="originalTitle"]/node()[not(self::span)]') %>%
    html_text()
```

I'm just getting "The LEGO Movie" as output which is what you need

Comment: I've tried a few variations of this, but everytime it cuts a post into smaller pieces (something I do not want). And it cuts on html tags.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39506292/rvest-getting-node-text-and-not-its-childens-text) person had the same issue and it seemed to work. The scenarios are alike, right?

Comment: Apparently not. He seems to remove every child, while I only want to remove a specific nested child. The structure I am trying to webscrape is used on most vbulletin websites, like: http://www.sportsforumpicks.com/forum/showthread.php?t=97323

Comment: Well, you're also removing every child, the thing is that every child for you means the only child. If you needed to remove a specific one you could tweak the xpath after `self::div` with some condition.

Comment: I just added an example. If that doesn't fit your HTML input, please provide a more accurate piece of code for me to test on